# A problem from KVS 2014

Tags: inequality

I was doing the the following problem-
**Prove that** $$\frac { \sqrt { a+b+c } +\sqrt { a }  }{ b+c } +\frac { \sqrt { a+b+c } +\sqrt { b }  }{ c+a } +\frac { \sqrt { a+b+c } +\sqrt { c }  }{ a+b } \ge \frac { 9+3\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2\sqrt { a+b+c } }. $$

I normalized this to $a+b+c=1$ and simplified to get-

$$\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { a }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { b }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { c }  } \ge \frac { 9+3\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }.$$
By Titu's lemma,
$$\Rightarrow \quad \frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { a }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { b }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { c }  } \ge \frac { 9 }{ 3-(\sqrt { a } +\sqrt { b } +\sqrt { c } ) } .$$

However the *RHS* is maximized when  $\sqrt { a } +\sqrt { b } +\sqrt { c } $ is maximized which is at $\sqrt { 3 } $,
$$\Rightarrow \quad \frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { a }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { b }  } +\frac { 1 }{ 1-\sqrt { c }  } \ge \frac { 9 }{ 3-(\sqrt { a } +\sqrt { b } +\sqrt { c } ) } \le \frac { 9 }{ 3-\sqrt { 3 }  } =\frac { 9+3\sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } .$$

What went wrong?

You can view the rest of the problems [here](http://www.mathmaa.com/17thKVS-JMO2014.html).

Comment: what is KVS 2014?

Comment: It is a mathematical olympiad restricted to the Kendriya Vidyalayas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}}$ for $0<x<1$ and the tangent line at the point $x=\frac{1}{3}$ we get $y=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})x+\frac{3}{4}$. We have for $0<x<1$ $$f(x)\geq \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})x+\frac{3}{4}$$. Thus we get $$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{c}}\geq \frac{3}{4}\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})(a+b+c)+\frac{9}{4}=\frac{1}{2}(9+3\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: could you please explain the "$y=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})x+\frac{3}{4}$" part? As in, how did you conclude this result?

Comment: this is the tangent line at $x=1/3$ of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}}$ it is the so called tangent line method

Comment: see here http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjACOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ust.hk%2Fexcalibur%2Fv10_n5.pdf&ei=T56ZVIjPHIbeOLKqgagC&usg=AFQjCNEjmkPzSzffzSYW2trnqOGBQ-KspA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.ZWU